# Retrosynthesis of a cyclopropane type molecule

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I'm trying to work out a retrosynthesis of the following molecule:

[image]

The issue I'm having is regarding the building up of the carbon skeleton. I know I can build the cyclopropane group using a carbene (diiodomethane, zinc) on the alkene. However, the alkene is proving difficult to build, I can't see why an obvious way around building this (Witting/from the equivalent alkyne) wouldn't work here. Is there something I am missing here like a rearrangement?

Comment: Alkyne seems workable.

Comment: @orthocresol I guess you could start with methyl propiolate, then could deprotonate the alkyne and get the other part on the alkyne, however the equivalent for that would be something like 2-bromo-2-methoxypropane which isn't readily available and can't really think of a synthetic equivalent for it

Comment: Count your carbons again - you should deprotonate acetylene and react with acetone, followed by methylation of the alkoxide. Then you deprotonate again and add methyl chloroformate or something. Lindlar hydrogenation and cyclopropanation would give you the desired compound.

Comment: @orthocresol Would the deprotonated alkyne react with acetone without any other reagent? The rest makes sense, to get the correct stereochemistry would just hydrogenate with Lindlar's catalyst and use the carbene to make the cyclopropane. Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: As far as I know alkynes (or their conjugate bases to be precise) generally add to carbonyls without issues, I think acetone should be no different.

Comment: You will need to protect the ester though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this? Cyclopropane from carbene + maleic anhydride. Add 2 eq methyl Grignard and trap with methyl iodide.

Possibly, you could do the exhaustive addition of Grignard first, then cyclopropanate and methylate in one shot with diazomethane. Thanks to Beerhunter for this suggestion in comments.

Comment: very much nicer than making it from the alkyne!

Comment: Did you mean carbene rather than methyl carbene? This is a lovely proposal. I would rejig this slightly to use the double methyl addition first, then acidic work up to give the gamma hydroxyacid. From there, exhaustive reaction with diazomethane (done by Aerojet on plant scale), with manipulation of conditions, to methylate the hydroxy, the acid and make the ring in one go. I'm not posting this as an answer as the one above is the definitive starting point for a strategy.

Comment: Yes, I meant carbene. Sorry for the confusion. Fixed. I'm also going to include your suggestion to cyclopropanate afterwards.